# VS2015 deploying web app throws "Exception in executing publishing: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

When I try to redeploy my webapp project to Azure through VS2015 (Professional) Publish I get an "Exception in executing publishing: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". No further explanation.
I build the project in VS2015 using framework 4.6
Tried some of the solutions that occured in other versions of VS like rebuilding, reloading and deleting the "packages" folder. No dice though.

The latest VS2015 Service Pack 1 did not resolve the issue either.

I ended up deploying through VS2013, the project didnt throw an exception when using Publish. Did a downgrade to framework 4.5 first.